# Need help in identifying a specific italian salami/sausage for pizza

Tags: meat, pizza, food-identification, salami

I came across a very intense and savory salami recently at a great pizzeria in Frankfurt (Germany). The pizza guys however are from Napoli and sell their amazing and traditional pizza since ages with a salami I have never seen somewhere else and which I could not identify up until now.

Does anyone have an idea, what type of salami is used here (see pictures below)? They call it salami but it doesn't have to be a salami in a narrow sense. It is very finely ground and looks rather like a typical sausage (like mortadella/lyoner etc.) when cooked and raw.

I would be very happy about any hint that helps to identify the name of this specific salami.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What was the name of the pizza you ordered? That might be a clue.

Comment: Are they both the same salami?

Comment: Is it possible this is a German salumi?

Comment: @hb20007 Name of the pizza is: Napoli de Luxe (toppings: Salami, Mushrooms, spicy pepperoni sausage)

Comment: @Tetsujin: Yes, same salami on both pictures

Comment: @moscafj: No, this is not a german salami.

Comment: Totally not an answer, but just a thought - Do you know Z/Cervelat? Tastes like the more grainy salami, but is ground finer?

Comment: @Stephie: Cervelat comes very close in taste and appearance but it still isn't the type of sausage they use. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

Salami is a generic term referring to all sorts of salt cured or cooked sausage, from a variety of countries and cultures.  My guess is that pictured is German [fleischwirst](https://www.asausagehastwo.com/german-sausage-guide-fleischwurst/) or [extrawurst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrawurst) (Austrian cousin).  The Italian version is [mortadella](https://www.bologna4you.com/post/what-is-mortadella), but typically has white chunks of fat and pistachio nuts.

Comment: Well put! In fact, the sausage looks so much like a German "Fleischwurst" or like a Turkish "Sucuk" but it is not the same. It assumes it is something for the Napoli area in Italy.

Comment: @Daniel I would be happy to be proven wrong, but I don't think this is a salumi from Italy, or from Campagna specifically.  Perhaps it is just "marketing" to call it Napoli de Luxe.

Comment: @Daniel Virtually nothing about that pizza is “traditional Neapolitan”. (That’s not a bad thing; Naples doesn’t have exclusive license to decide what good pizza is like.) It’s likely that local sausage is being used.

Comment: But as a German, I can’t pinpoint a German sausage that would fit…

Comment: @Sneftel: Yes, might be a local one. They have been operating their pizzaria for more than 50 years now and might have move away from traditional italian ingredients in the meantime. However, I don't have any idea what local sausage this might be.

Comment: I'm afraid the local sausage is likely something like "Italian-style Pre-Cooked Salami Sausage, 30mm Diameter, 300mm Length" from their food supplier. That is, the exact details are specific to the source, and you won't be able to find the exact same thing in a market.

Comment: @Sneftel you are probably right... I already checked the local cash and carry store with the attributes you mentioned but did not find anything like this. Anyways, thanks for your support!

Comment: Very often, the only thing 'Italian' in a pizza restaurant is the red-white-and-green colour scheme.